# Как добавить одинаковый класс DIV-ам с разным ID

Tags: javascript, html

Есть код:

```
.......
<div id="modifier-1" class="modifier">........</div>
<div id="modifier-2" class="modifier">........</div>
<div id="modifier-3" class="modifier">........</div>
<div id="modifier-4" class="modifier">........</div>
......
```

И есть class="mod-before". 
Подскажите как можно с помощью JS добавить еще этот класс ко всем  этим ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выбрать все элементы у которых атрибут `id` начинающийся с `modifier`, выбирается с помощью `^=`.

В итоге имеет выборку вида: `div[id^="modifier"]`

```js
// JavaScript
var divs = document.querySelectorAll('div[id^="modifier"]');
var i = divs.length
while(i--) {
  divs[i].classList.add('mod-before');
}
console.log(divs[0], divs[1]);
```

```html
<div id="modifier-1" class="modifier">........</div>
<div id="modifier-2" class="modifier">........</div>
<div id="modifier-3" class="modifier">........</div>
<div id="modifier-4" class="modifier">........</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, вопрос решен, именно это и было нужно div[id^="modifier"]

Answer (score 0):

выбрать все дивы с классом *modifier*, например с помощью функции [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

Пробежаться в цикле по выбранным дивам и добавить каждому нужный класс, например с помощью функции [`classList.add`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)

Comment: Дело в том, что класс ''modiier'' используется и в других местах кода, а добавить класс "mod-before" нужно только этим ID

Comment: @Андрей, этим, это каким? ну и проще всего использовать для нужных дивов другой класс тогда и по нему выбирать